# Creating a histogram or bar plot from a csv where each row has a different number of items in R

Tags: r

I was given a csv with 3000 rows that looks like this:

```
x17482 y34
x29287 y45
x90374 y47 y37
x83902 y29
x93403 y86 y59 y68 y98
```

Each y value is a unique Ensembl gene ID, and the x's are also all unique. Some rows have up to 60 y-values in them.

I was asked to plot a histogram (it seems like they may actually want a bar plot instead) of the distribution of x-values to see how many rows only have one gene ID and how many rows have 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. gene IDs in them. How do I go about doing this?

I tried using t() to flip the data frame to have x as my header, but I'm having a really hard time dealing with this table in its current form.

I was thinking I could just count the number of items in each row and store that as a vector and plot that? How would I create a script that counts the number of y-values in each row and just returns the number of items in that row? Something like:

```
x17482 1
x29287 1
x90374 2
x83902 1
x93403 4
```

I'm new to programming so if there's an easier way I could do this, please help lol. Thank you!

Comment: Please include a sample of the data as an r object, paste the output of `dput(your_csv_sample)` into the question, this makes it easier for others to test solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this??

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = '"x17482" "y34"
  "x29287" "y45"
  "x90374" "y47 y37"
  "x83902" "y29"
  "x93403" "y86 y59 y68 y98"', header = F)

df %>% 
  mutate(y_count = 1 + str_count(V2, ' ')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y_count)) +
  geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

---

or perhaps this

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(y_count = 1 + str_count(V2, ' ')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y_count)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Good to see you again and to learn more from you dear AnilGoyal!

Comment: Ohhh, this looks like exactly what I want, thank you very much! I’ll try it out.